# Sending mail from PHP - is the error at my end, or the Mail Server's?

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, smtp

I'm trying to send email via SMTP from my PHP script, running via CodeIgniter.

See below for the debug output. Is this indicative of a problem at my end with PHP (`Unable to send email using PHP SMTP`) or at their end (`hello: 250-parrot.email-provider.co.uk` - which would imply to me it has connected to their server, as the actual SMTP server I entered was `mail2.email-provider.co.uk`, so it seems to connect and redirect to this `parrot` thing).

My SMTP details I have confirmed to be correct, but it still says it fails to authenticate the password - even though this same password works in my native mail clients.

I've changed my site name and the provider's name (I didn't want to name-and-shame if it was my fault!):

```
220 parrot.email-provider.co.uk ESMTP Postfix 
hello: 250-parrot.email-provider.co.uk
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 512000000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
from: 250 2.1.0 Ok
to: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
The following SMTP error was encountered: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied 
to: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
The following SMTP error was encountered: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied 
to: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
The following SMTP error was encountered: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied 
data: 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
The following SMTP error was encountered: 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients 
221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye. 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye. 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 7 Dec 2011 13:30:16 +0000
From: "Mysite.com" 
Return-Path: 
To: myemail@email.com
Cc: myotheremail@email.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?The_Subject?=
Reply-To: "mail@mysite.com" 
X-Sender: mail@mysite.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <4edf6a68626d6@mysite.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: What does your actual PHP code look like? And especially the part where you set the authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the codeigniter mail object, try:
$this->email->print_debugger()

Brute force method, go up one level from application and put in log_message/trace,etc, to debug the actual codeigniter code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Can be:

1. Wrong password.
2. Login method not allowed/recognized by server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have set everything fine and got the same message.

The problem was in the fact that I have set `to` address with `$this->email->to` before I have applied smtp settings with `$this->email->initialize($config)`. After I moved this line before all other settings, everything worked as it is supposed.